# Android,Room,RxJava how to combine query results into one map and return as flowable

Tags: android

Here i have 3 methods to get 3 different types of data-list
These codes below are inside the

```
@Dao
public interface  GlassesDao {
  @Query("SELECT * FROM len")
  Flowable<List<Glasses>> getAllLens();

  @Query("SELECT * FROM frame")
  Flowable<List<Glasses>> getAllFrames();

  @Query("SELECT * FROM framecolor")
  Flowable<List<Glasses>> getAllFrameColors();
```

Now i want it return them as a map

```
@Transaction //idk if Transaction is used like this
Flowable<Map<String, List<Glasses>>> getAll()
```

and btw some aditional questions but still refer to the title,i think:
Is the code i used to get  object list correct? if not how to make it?

#### And one more: how should i design the entity?

for now there are 3 child-classes of class "Glasses" and i want 3 tables from these three childs but no need glasses*(actually there's no real "Glasses" with only 3 parameters needed like the above code shows "len,frame,framecolor")***But i have to use  parent-child pattern, cause i need combine them into one list** ,like what the map showed.

```
Map<String, List<Glasses>>
```

Idk if my questions are understood,but thank you for your precious time!

Comment: You can do it manually. Just return Single and then zip them altogether.

Comment: thank you for the reply! And if you can pls show something detail or some link

Comment: I will try to post an example then we can work it out. Please wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this.

```
Flowable.zip(database.dao().getAllLens(),
        database.dao().getAllFrames(),
        database.dao().getAllFrameColors(),
        new Function3<List<Glasses>, List<Glasses>, List<Glasses>, Map<String, List<Glasses>>>() {
            @Override
            public Map<String, List<Glasses>> apply(List<Glasses> o, List<Glasses> o2, List<Glasses> o3) throws Exception {
                /* Perform map population here */
            }
});
```

Comment: And this should working or at lest it give me many helps ! But i'll not use database for this case now. It's small size of data anyway...